# Get related Products in the WooCommerce widget Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

Does anyone have any idea how you can put related products in the sidebar in WooCommerce?

Something like in this screenshot:

[image: Reference image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use this code to enable Shortcode execution in the text widget

```
// Enable shortcode execution in text widget
add_filter ('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

2) Then in Wordpress widget, you will able to add and use the text widget adding to it:

```
[related_products per_page="4" columns="1"]
```

[image]

> But you will have to make some custom CSS for it, to get the display that you want… Or to build your own custom widget (or shortcode).

Comment: yes, for the moment it works for me, I'm just working on the custom css.